# How to change the height of popup box in magic zoom plus

Tags: javascript, magiczoomplus

I am facing some problem not exactly the problem I want little change in this script.Actually I want to change the height of the `magic zoom plus window' but I am not able to find the solution reason is that I am not more aware with javascript.you can see from here

http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/

In this example when mouse over the `bike image` then the selected portion of `bike` shown in other window I want to change the size of that window.

Please provide me any help regard this.I shall be very thankful to u.
Please reply me ASAP

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the options parameter

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        MagicZoomPlus.options = {
            'opacity': 30,
            'background-opacity': 70,
            'show-title': 'bottom',
            'zoom-height': '100'
        };
    </script>
```

Source: http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/integration/